# Plugging computer on monitor with multiple cables

Tags: display

Let's say I have a tower with two DVI outputs out of the graphics card, a DVI-VGA adapter, a DVI-DVI cable and a VGA-VGA cable, and finally, a monitor which has DVI and VGA inputs.

Would there be any benefit or downside for plugging the tower to the monitor using the two ports simultaneously?

I am aware this is more of a curiosity question, please let me know if it is not suited here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would not be any benefit of doing this, but there's not really a downside to it either, other than maybe some boot display issues.

The DVI port will query a device once connected. A monitor that has the input source not set to that DVI port, will show up as disconnected to the OS, which basically means the same as not connecting it with a cable.

For VGA, this is different, because the cable is an analog cable. The OS detects a cable plugged in and even if the source is not set to that monitor, the OS does sees a monitor is connected, it just can't query the display resolution, so it will default to the most basic resolution. Depending on the OS, this is usually either 640x480 or 800x600.

The only real benefit of this, is that it gives you this resolution extra to move windows to, and with additional software you could get those windows back or not. But if you go this route, a Virtual Desktop is a lot better because you get the same resolution as your monitor is for the virtual desktops, and you are not limited to just one additional desktop.

A VGA port may be used as primary port, which means that windows may try to show image to that port and not the DVI port during boot, which would mean that you don't see the boot sequence anymore while the cable is plugged in but the monitor is switched to the DVI source.

Answer (score 0):

As the monitor can only display one input at a time, the only effect would be, that you have to specify that the computer has to output only on one port, e.g. by setting the two ports to "mirror display" or disable one of them.

I don't know any benefits from duplicating the connection for normal use cases.
Maybe in some special environments, (nuclear reactors, aerospace) it MIGHT be of some use to have redundancy, but I can't really imagine, that this method is used.

However, there exist some special monitors, which can split the panel for two different inputs or allow picture in picture for two different inputs.
The first has a use for ultra wide screen monitors, because you can benefit from the window managers capabilities for multiple monitors. The example would be having windows in full-screen mode on half of the display. 
However, for the latter I don't see any use-case for driving them from the same PC, as you could achieve the same effect by using classical gui elements, like windows.

Comment: It is most likely that when you set the input for one port, windows detects no signal on the other and sets the output as disabled automatically. No need to set the display up as single monitor or mirrored. Only VGA has no option to know if a screen is really on or not and the connector itself will connect, but it will give a VGA of 640x480 or 800x600 depending on the windows version and cannot be changed unless the monitor is switched, but that will definitely disable the DVI port.

Comment: The special monitors that have this ultra-wide setup with 2 connectors do require either 2 DVI or Display ports (usually display ports only) as VGA (sub-d) is an analog signal only and does not have enough bandwidth. So it will not work with ultra-wide screens either.

Answer (score 0):

Computer would detect this setup as two separate monitors. You could enable extended desktop to use it as a weird and uncomfortable virtual desktop solution. Operating system would think that "both" monitors are connected, but you could switch between desktop using monitor buttons/menu options.

Would it be useful? Not really. Windows 10 and most Linux desktop environments have built in virtual desktop feature, which can be controlled using mouse or keyboard and is quicker (monitors take time to switch between inputs).

Comment: It is most likely that when you set the input for one port, windows detects no signal on the other and sets the output as disabled, rendering this option pretty useless.